# Guice: One "Provider<T>" for multiple implementations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I have an interface that has 20 or so annotated implementations. I can inject the correct one if I know which I need at compile time, but I now need to dynamically inject one based on runtime parameters.

As I understood the documentation, I would have to use 20 or so `Provider<T>` injections and then use the one I need, which seems rather excessive to me. Is there a way to have something like an `inst(Provider<T>).get(MyAnnotation.class)` to bind a specific implementation, and then have only that `Provider` injected into my class?

Comment: Looks like a job for [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inject a [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html).

In your module, load the bindings into the `MapBinder`, then make your runtime parameters injectable as well. This example is based on the one in the documentation:

```
public class SnacksModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, Snack> mapbinder
           = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, Snack.class);
    mapbinder.addBinding("twix").to(Twix.class);
    mapbinder.addBinding("snickers").to(Snickers.class);
    mapbinder.addBinding("skittles").to(Skittles.class);
  }
}
```

Then, in your object, inject the `Map` and the parameter. For this example I will assume you've bound a [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for your runtime parameters:

```
@Inject
public MyObject(Map<String, Provider<Snack>> snackProviderMap, Properties properties) {
  String snackType = (String) properties.get("snackType");
  Provider<Snack> = snackProviderMap.get(property);
  
  // etc.
}
```

Note, with the same `MapBinder` you can inject either a simple `Map<String, Snack>` or a `Map<String, Provider<Snack>>`; Guice binds both.

Comment: Runtime parameters are a bit more complicated and cannot be injectable, which is the reason I need Provider<T> in order to obtain the implementation at a later time. However, what you described seems like a proper way to go. I assume that `newMapBinder` registers itself with the IoC?

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to pass `binder()` into the construction method. [You can also use AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) to pass the runtime parameters in if that would work better. Do you need me to explain that?

Comment: Hi, no need, thanks, I am familiar with AssistedInject (at least I think I am :)) but I couldn't see a solution using that. However, your MapBinder example is what I needed, I made a `MapBinder<MyEnum, MyInterface>` and am now able to query it even without annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to get an instance programmatically, you can inject an Injector. It's rarely a good idea--injecting a `Provider<T>` is a much better idea where you can, especially for the sake of testing--but to get a binding reflectively it's the only way to go.

```
class YourClass {
  final YourDep yourDep;  // this is the dep to get at runtime

  @Inject YourClass(Injector injector) {
    YourAnnotation annotation = deriveYourAnnotation();
    // getProvider would work here too.
    yourDep = injector.getInstance(Key.get(YourDep.class, annotation));
  }
}
```

If you're trying write a Provider that takes a parameter, the best way to express this is to write  a small Factory.

```
class YourDepFactory {
  @Inject @A Provider<YourDep> aProvider;
  @Inject @B Provider<YourDep> bProvider;
  // and so forth

  Provider<YourDep> getProvider(YourParameter parameter) {
    if (parameter.correspondsToA()) {
      return aProvider;
    } else if (parameter.correspondsToB()) {
      return bProvider;
    }
  }

  YourDep get(YourParameter parameter) {
    return getProvider(parameter);
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about the factory, but if you look at your own example, it just looks like an emulation of `Map<Tk, To>` and I would still need to maintain that Map outside of Module, which is what I wanted to avoid (as well as injecting Injector)

Comment: That's absolutely true, and especially important if the number of possibilities is extremely large (so it can resolve in constant time). If your selection logic is more like a predicate, though—such as when your Provider choice depends on multiple parameters—the factory pattern may be necessary. (You could also back it with a Map, too.)